# Changing div background color using switch statement

Tags: javascript, html, dom, switch-statement

Pardon the super-beginner troubles, but I'm trying to make a div change color using a javascript switch. I'm sure the issue has something to do with a fundamental misunderstanding of how parameters work, but as I said, I'm a newbie. I don't get any errors, it just doesn't do anything. Also, first post here, so I apologize if I did anything improper in my post.

```js
function colorChanger(color) {
  switch(color) {
  case "red":
   document.getElementById("color_box").style.backgroundColor = "red";
   break;
  case "orange":
   document.getElementById("color_box").style.backgroundColor = "orange";
   break;
  case "yellow":
   document.getElementById("color_box").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
   break;
  case "green":
   document.getElementById("color_box").style.backgroundColor = "green";
   break;
  case "blue":
   document.getElementById("color_box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
   break;
  case "indigo":
   document.getElementById("color_box").style.backgroundColor = "indigo";
   break;
  case "violet":
   document.getElementById("color_box").style.backgroundColor = "violet";
   break;  
 }
}
```

```css
@viewport {
    zoom: 1.0;
    width: device-width;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#color_box {
 width: 20rem;
 height: 20rem;
 border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Color Buttons</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./color_buttons.css">
 <script src="color_buttons.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="color_box">
</div>
<div id="button_box">
 <button type="button" id="red" onclick="colorChanger(red)">Red</button>
 <button type="button" id="orange" onclick="colorChanger(orange)">Orange</button>
 <button type="button" id="yellow" onclick="colorChanger(yellow)">Yellow</button>
 <button type="button" id="green" onclick="colorChanger(green)">Green</button>
 <button type="button" id="blue" onclick="colorChanger(blue)">Blue</button>
 <button type="button" id="indigo" onclick="colorChanger(indigo)">Indigo</button>
 <button type="button" id="violet" onclick="colorChanger(violet)">Violet</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need quotes around the arguments to make them strings.

```
<button type="button" id="red" onclick="colorChanger('red')">Red</button>
```

Without quotes, it's looking for a variable named `red`.

The reason you didn't get an error is because the colors are the same as the IDs of the buttons, and IDs all become global variables that refer to the corresponding DOM elements. So it's acting like you wrote:

```
onclick="colorChanger(document.getElementById('red'))"
```

Since this isn't equal to any of the cases in the `switch` statement, nothing happens.

BTW, why bother with the switch statement? Just do:

```
document.getElementById("color_box").style.backgroundColor = color;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes around the arguments to make them strings. Otherwise just pass the id using `this.id`

```js
function colorChanger(color) {
  switch(color) {
  case "red":
   document.getElementById("color_box").style.backgroundColor = "red";
   break;
  case "orange":
   document.getElementById("color_box").style.backgroundColor = "orange";
   break;
  case "yellow":
   document.getElementById("color_box").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
   break;
  case "green":
   document.getElementById("color_box").style.backgroundColor = "green";
   break;
  case "blue":
   document.getElementById("color_box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
   break;
  case "indigo":
   document.getElementById("color_box").style.backgroundColor = "indigo";
   break;
  case "violet":
   document.getElementById("color_box").style.backgroundColor = "violet";
   break;  
 }
}
```

```css
@viewport {
    zoom: 1.0;
    width: device-width;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#color_box {
 width: 20rem;
 height: 20rem;
 border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Color Buttons</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./color_buttons.css">
 <script src="color_buttons.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="color_box">
</div>
<div id="button_box">
 <button type="button" id="red" onclick="colorChanger(this.id)">Red</button>
 <button type="button" id="orange" onclick="colorChanger(this.id)">Orange</button>
 <button type="button" id="yellow" onclick="colorChanger(this.id)">Yellow</button>
 <button type="button" id="green" onclick="colorChanger(this.id)">Green</button>
 <button type="button" id="blue" onclick="colorChanger(this.id)">Blue</button>
 <button type="button" id="indigo" onclick="colorChanger(this.id)">Indigo</button>
 <button type="button" id="violet" onclick="colorChanger(this.id)">Violet</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And as @Barmar says  why bother with the switch statement? Just do:

`document.getElementById("color_box").style.backgroundColor = color;` like this

```js
function colorChanger(color) {
  document.getElementById("color_box").style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```css
@viewport {
  zoom: 1.0;
  width: device-width;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#color_box {
  width: 20rem;
  height: 20rem;
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Color Buttons</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./color_buttons.css">
  <script src="color_buttons.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="color_box">
  </div>
  <div id="button_box">
    <button type="button" id="red" onclick="colorChanger(this.id)">Red</button>
    <button type="button" id="orange" onclick="colorChanger(this.id)">Orange</button>
    <button type="button" id="yellow" onclick="colorChanger(this.id)">Yellow</button>
    <button type="button" id="green" onclick="colorChanger(this.id)">Green</button>
    <button type="button" id="blue" onclick="colorChanger(this.id)">Blue</button>
    <button type="button" id="indigo" onclick="colorChanger(this.id)">Indigo</button>
    <button type="button" id="violet" onclick="colorChanger(this.id)">Violet</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Totally blew my mind with all this stuff! I love it!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use jQuery:

```js
 $('button').click(function(){
   var id = this.id
  
  switch(id){
   case "red":
    $('#color_box').css('background-color', 'red');
    break;
   case "orange":
    $('#color_box').css('background-color', 'orange');
    break;
   case "yellow":
    $('#color_box').css('background-color', 'yellow');
    break;
   case "green":
    $('#color_box').css('background-color', 'green');
    break;
   case "blue":
    $('#color_box').css('background-color', 'blue');
    break;
   case "indigo":
    $('#color_box').css('background-color', 'indigo');
    break;
   case "violet":
    $('#color_box').css('background-color', 'violet');
    break;

  }
 });
```

```css
 @viewport {
  zoom: 1.0;
  width: device-width;
 }

 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 #color_box {
  width: 20rem;
  height: 20rem;
  border: solid 1px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="color_box">
</div>
<div id="button_box">
 <button type="button" id="red">Red</button>
 <button type="button" id="orange">Orange</button>
 <button type="button" id="yellow">Yellow</button>
 <button type="button" id="green">Green</button>
 <button type="button" id="blue">Blue</button>
 <button type="button" id="indigo">Indigo</button>
 <button type="button" id="violet">Violet</button>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass color name parameters as a string, Wrap all the color names with single quotes like while calling function `colorChanger('color')`

```
    <button type="button" id="red" onclick="colorChanger('red')">Red</button>
    <button type="button" id="orange" onclick="colorChanger('orange')">Orange</button>
    <button type="button" id="yellow" onclick="colorChanger('yellow')">Yellow</button>
    <button type="button" id="green" onclick="colorChanger('green')">Green</button>
    <button type="button" id="blue" onclick="colorChanger('blue')">Blue</button>
    <button type="button" id="indigo" onclick="colorChanger('indigo')">Indigo</button>
    <button type="button" id="violet" onclick="colorChanger('violet')">Violet</button>
```